# Intercept external URL fetch via ServiceWorker running on localhost

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, service-worker

I have a set of integration tests which run in Karma. Unfortunately, they call out to an external, production API endpoint. I do not want integration tests to call out and am exploring my options.

I am wondering if service workers are a viable solution. My assumption is that they do not work because https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1188 makes it clear that cross-origin fetch is not supported and localhost is not the same origin as a production API endpoint.

For clarity, here is some code I am running:

```
  try {
    const { scope, installing, waiting, active } = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('./base/htdocs/test/imageMock.sw.js');
    console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', scope, installing, waiting, active);


    (installing || waiting || active).addEventListener('statechange', (e) => {
      console.log('state', e.target.state);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', error);
  }
```

and the service worker

```
// imageMock.sw.js

if (typeof self.skipWaiting === 'function') {
  console.log('self.skipWaiting() is supported.');
  self.addEventListener('install', (e) => {
    // See https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/index.html#service-worker-global-scope-skipwaiting
    e.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
  });
} else {
  console.log('self.skipWaiting() is not supported.');
}

if (self.clients && (typeof self.clients.claim === 'function')) {
  console.log('self.clients.claim() is supported.');
  self.addEventListener('activate', (e) => {
    // See https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/index.html#clients-claim-method
    e.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
  });
} else {
  console.log('self.clients.claim() is not supported.');
}

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  console.log('fetching resource', event);
  if (/\.jpg$/.test(event.request.url)) {
    const response = new Response('<p>This is a response that comes from your service worker!</p>', {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' },
    });

    event.respondWith(response);
  }
});
```

and when this code is ran I see in the console

```
ServiceWorker registration successful with scope:  http://localhost:9876/base/htdocs/test/ null null ServiceWorker
```

and then requests to `https://<productionServer>.com/image.php` are not intercepted by the fetch handler.

Is it correct that there is no way to intercept in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can** use a service worker to intercept requests made by a browser as part of a test suite. As long a service worker is in control of a web page, it can intercept cross-origin requests and generate any response you'd like.

(The [issue you link to](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1188) about "foreign fetch" is something different; think of it as the remote production server deploying its own service worker. This was abandoned.)

"[Stop mocking fetch](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/stop-mocking-fetch)" is a comprehensive article covering how to use the [`msw`](https://mswjs.io/) service worker library within the context of a test suite.

I can't say off the top of my head exactly why your current setup isn't working, but from past experience, I can say that the most important thing to remember when doing this is that you need to delay making any requests from a client test page until the page itself is being controlled by an active service worker. Otherwise, there's a race condition in which you might end up  firing off a request that needs to trigger a `fetch` handler, but won't if the service worker isn't yet in control.

You can wait for this to happen with logic like:

```js
const controlledPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  // Resolve right away if this page is already controlled.
  if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
    resolve();
  } else {
    navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', () => {
      resolve();
    });
  }
});

await controlledPromise;
// At this point, the page will be controlled by a service worker.
// You can start making requests at this point.
```

Note that for this use case, `await navigator.serviceWorker.ready` will not give you the behavior you need, as there can be a gap in time between when the [`navigator.serviceWorker.ready` promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/ready) resolves and when the newly activated service worker takes control of the current page. You don't want that gap of time to lead to flaky tests.